# Error building Flutter app: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart, gradle

When I try to build my Flutter app in vscode, I get the following error about not using the correct Java version.

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/x/test/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11.
      Your current JDK is located in /opt/android-studio-2021.2.1/android-studio/jre
      You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
```

Running `gradlew --version` from the flutter project's `android` folder gives the output

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-02-13 13:15:21 UTC
Revision:     62ab9b7c7f884426cf79fbedcf07658b2dbe9e97

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.13
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.7 (Private Build 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.2)
OS:           Linux 5.19.0-41-generic amd64
```

Opened up the `android` folder in Android Studio and I have already set `Gradle JDK` to version 20

[image]

In my `android/build.gradle` I have

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
    
      ...
```

in `android/app/build.gradle` I have

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    ...
```

In `gradle-wrapper.properties` I have

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
```

How can I get Flutter to use Java 20 when building the app?

Comment: Try to define this in your build.gradle: `sourceCompatibility = 1.17`

Comment: @SebPerp Same build error if I replace `android.compileOptions.sourceCompability` from `sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` to `sourceCompatibility 1.17`

Comment: In AS, one need to download JDK 17 and set it as default for the project and/or IDE. I suspect it is the same for VS Code, just make sure it builds using JDK 17.

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

}
```